# OpenStack API returns no server details

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I cannot see the detail of servers when I send request to `/servers/detail` via port `8774`. I get the response same as the `/servers`. In both request I get the `300` status code. It returns a list of choices. In both cases of sending token and not sending it I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you get a 300 response when you’re using an end point that is offered in several flavors and you need to specifically set  the API version in your request.

See https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/

You will for example need to use `http://mycompute.api.example.com:8774/compute/v2.1/servers/detail` when for example both a V1.1 and V2.1 API version are offered and you want to use the 2.1 version.

Comment: Thanks. when I use `/compute/v2.1/servers/detail`, I get 300 with multiple choices `v2/compute/v2.1/servers/detail`, `v2.1/compute/v2.1/servers/detail`. when I use each of them I get 404.